# How can I create a new .txt file with the name of the class in which the method was called?

Tags: java, file, class

I am new to programming, so let's see if I can explain this well enough.

I am making a Java package. In one of the classes there is a method that creates a file. The name of that file I have it set up as "file.txt", but I want to change it.

Let's say there is a user working on a new project and he imports the library `package` (the one I am working on). I want for the file that is created to take the name of the class in which the user is working on. For example if the user calls it in a class named `Main`, I want the file to be called `main.txt` or `Main.txt`.

If this is not clear enough please let me know, I'll try to explain it better.

Thanks

Edit:
The `getClass().getSimpleName()` doesn't work exactly like I want it to. The method is located inside a library called `library` and the class is called `Main.class` but is being used by a use that imported the library `library` and is working on a class called `SuperMario.class` I want the text file to be called `SuperMario.txt` instead with `getClass().getSimpleName()` applied to my method the file will be called `Main.txt`, because that is the name of the class the method is in. Unfortunately I can't pass the name as a parameter either. Can anyone think of a way around this?

edit: I managed to get the program to behave how I wanted it to, I posted my answer. Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: `getClass().getName()`?

Comment: @Smutje - Ya, but the method shouldn't be static :)

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar `Main.class.getName()` :-P

Comment: @Smutje - In that case the Op might as well enter 'Main' directly :P

Comment: If `SuperMario` extends `Mario`, calling `getClass()` from within `Mario` when `this` is an instance of `SuperMario` will return `SuperMario.class`, and calling `getSimpleName()` on that will return `SuperMario`. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP I answered the question below, but basically I wanted my package to create a file, and this file would take the name of whatever class the user was working on. I didn't want the file to have the package name for example:

`import myPKG.*;`

`public class Main {`
    `public static void main(String[] args){`
        `myPKG.fileCreator();`
        }
   }
now the file that gets created will be called "Main.txt" because the package function was called from the Main class. If it wad been called from any other class it would have taken that name accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, but thank you all for the suggestions. 
I ended up using `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName()`

```
String name = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName();
File file = new File(name + ".txt");
```

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getClass().getSimpleName()`, this will give you the class name in Java

Comment: This doesn't work exactly like I want it to. The method is located inside a library called `library` and the class is called `Main.class` but is being used by a use that imported the `library` library and is working on a class called `SuperMario.class` I want the text file to be called `SuperMario.txt` instead with this method the file will be called `Main.txt`. Unfortunately I can't pass the name as a parameter either.